# Tag [bandcamp] should exist. Also, there should be less reputation needed to create tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

There is a [soundcloud](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundcloud) tag already with 26 usages. There should be a [bandcamp](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bandcamp) tag. It's a very similar website in purpose. Both have their own special features but they're both fundamentally made for music producers to share their songs.

By the way, I think this site should consider lowering the reputation requirement to create new tags. The reason is that the world of web applications is very rapidly changing. New tools pop up all the time, and there are enumerable sites that could feasibly discussed here but that nobody's added as a tag. If the reputation requirement were lower, then people would have an easier time posting their questions here since they don't have to limit themselves to the existing tags. If more people posted, the site would become more useful as a general-purpose webapps Q&A site.

Answer (score 4):

We don't create tags ahead of time. There needs to be a question that needs the tag before the tag can be created. I only see [one question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60505) that seems to be about Bandcamp on the whole site, and it's from 2014. I'll wager that the [bandcamp](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bandcamp) tag *did* exist, but was eventually deleted because it's only on one question. I'll add the tag to that question, but unless other questions appear for that tag, it'll eventually be deleted again.

As for lowering the rep requirement for making new tags, it's only 300 points. That should be quite low for someone who has spent time on the site and has a decent understanding of how the site in general and tags in particular are supposed to work. What we don't need are a bunch of junk tags, which is what we'll get if we let all and sundry create tags. We're *still* trying to get rid of some. (See, for instance, the posts on Meta tagged [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up).

On another note, your question is really two questions: One is a support request to get a tag created. The other is a feature request to lower the reputation threshold for creating new tags. They really should be separate questions, so that each issue can be addressed (and voted on) separately. Anyone with sufficient reputation can act on the first, but it'll require a developer to address the second. For the future, we'll all be better served if you split them into separate questions.

See also:

- Meta FAQ: [Can we please have the {foo} tag on our site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949/21960) (*i.e.*, how to get a tag created when you don't have the privilege)
- Questions requesting an *increase* in the threshold:

  - [Please raise the tag creation reputation threshold on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55490/21960)
  - [Should the create-new-tag threshold be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51949/21960)
  - [New tag should require more privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137833/21960)